# Java get the excel cell background color from Apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, xlsx

I am trying to get cell color info in *.xlsx* file using Apache POI.

Method `cellStyle.getFillBackgroundColor()` is returning short. How can I convert short to `java.awt.Color` or any other format(`XSSFColor`).

Ultimately I want to store the value of cell based on its background color.

```
 Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream (new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH)));
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
    sheet.forEach(row -> {
        row.forEach(cell -> {
            String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
            System.out.println(cellStyle.getFillBackgroundColor());
            //Color userColor = cellStyle.getFillBackgroundColor(); //ERROR 
        });
        System.out.println();
    });
```

I am using version 3.6 which I think do not support getFillBackgroundColorColor()

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why are you using version 3.6?  That version was released in 2009.

Comment: Legacy app in production. Need lot of testing before I change the version of any jar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With .xlsx spreadsheets, you can call [the `getFillBackgroundColorColor` (2 "Color" words)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#getFillBackgroundColorColor--) method.  It returns an `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Color` (not a very useful interface), that `XSSFColor` implements.  Then you can cast it as `XSSFColor`.

```
XSSFColor = (XSSFColor) cellStyle.getFillBackgroundColorColor();
```

Alternatively, again with .xlxs spreadsheets, you can cast the `CellStyle` as an `XSSFCellStyle`, and `XSSFCellStyle`'s `getFillBackgroundColorColor` method returns an `XSSFColor` directly.  It also has [`getFillBackgroundXSSFColor`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#getFillBackgroundXSSFColor--) which does the same thing.

> Get the background fill color.
>
> Note - many cells are actually filled with a foreground fill, not a background fill - see [`getFillForegroundColor()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#getFillForegroundColor--)

Beware that solid fills are implemented as foreground colors, so the foreground color may be what you're really after.  There are complementary methods for the foreground color, e.g. `getFillForegroundColorColor`.

Comment: How can I retrieve the hexadecimal value or color code (like Hex:   #E5FFCC) from XSSFColor obj.

Comment: It was the solution for me: not `getFillBackgroundColorColor` but `getFillForegroundColorColor`, as the background color of the cell is the foreground one of its filling,